# Cannot read properly CSV file with PySpark

Tags: csv, pyspark

I'm trying to read a csv dataset with spark but not being able to read it properly because many of the columns are null or not even being charged.. As you all can see in the attachment. The columns inside the file are not empty but they are being showed as null.

I tried many ways of reading but got the same results... I even tried to exclude some columns to test but nothing.

PS: Here you can download the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tariqsays/chatgpt-twitter-dataset

It is a big file.. I'm not sure I can upload it here.

[image]

Thanks in advance. I'd be really happy if someone could help me

[image]

I tried many ways of reading but got the same results... I even tried to exclude some columns to test but nothing.

Comment: What if you add header=True and remove the inferSchema option?

Comment: It was one of my attempts. But it didn't work out.

Comment: As it's a big dataset, maybe you're only seeing the rows with null columns, but there's also other routes? Try specific filtering to find the rows you're looking for

Comment: I need to load the whole file. I don't want filter anything. I'm seeing nulls because something its wrong with the reading process

Comment: You're only showing the top 10 rows. If you show more or filter you can see if there is really something wrong with the reading.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the twitter dataset hosted at the kaggle link you provided. It seems the dataset is malformed. It is not in the expected csv format. It is corrupted. But no worries. Pandas can read multiline csv format properly.

So the idea is to first create a pandas dataframe from the csv and then use it to create pyspark dataframe. Here's how I did it.

Here's an example of multiline corrupted csv header and one row from the dataset :

```
Datetime,Tweet Id,Text,Username,Permalink,User,Outlinks,CountLinks,ReplyCount,RetweetCount,LikeCount,QuoteCount,ConversationId,Language,Source,Media,QuotedTweet,MentionedUsers,hashtag,hastag_counts
2023-01-22 13:44:34+00:00,1617156270871699456,"ChatGPTで遊ぶの忘れてた！！
書類作るコード書いてみてほしいのと、
どこまで思考整理付き合ってくれるのかと、
ウミガメのスープやってみたい。
あとは調べ物してくれ。
事務所でちょいといじったが、とりあえず色々やってみたい。",mochico0123,https://twitter.com/mochico0123/status/1617156270871699456,https://twitter.com/mochico0123,,,1,0,5,0,1617156270871699456,ja,"<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/iphone"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for iPhone</a>",,,,[],0
2023-01-22 13:44:39+00:00,1617156291046133761,@AlexandrovnaIng Prohibition of ChatGPT has been added to the honor code of my daughter’s school,Caput_LupinumSG,https://twitter.com/Caput_LupinumSG/status/1617156291046133761,https://twitter.com/Caput_LupinumSG,,,1,0,5,0,1617148639993806848,en,"<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/iphone"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for iPhone</a>",,,"[User(username='AlexandrovnaIng', id=2827059006, displayname='Alexandrovna', description=None, rawDescription=None, descriptionUrls=None, verified=None, created=None, followersCount=None, friendsCount=None, statusesCount=None, favouritesCount=None, listedCount=None, mediaCount=None, location=None, protected=None, linkUrl=None, linkTcourl=None, profileImageUrl=None, profileBannerUrl=None, label=None)]",[],0
2023-01-22 13:44:44+00:00,1617156308926349312,"Schaut Euch an, was @fobizz @DianaKnodel alles ⬇️ auf die Piste bringt, um Euch mitzunehmen.
```

To solve the corrupted rows problem, we do the following :

```
import sys

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

inputFile = "../data/chatgpt1.csv"

import pandas as pd
pdf = pd.read_csv(inputFile)


def print_pandas(dataframe_given):
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 10,'display.max_columns', None, 'expand_frame_repr', False):
        print("Given pandas dataframe name")
        print(dataframe_given)


print_pandas(pdf)


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .appName("read chatgpt twitter files") \
    .getOrCreate()
#Create PySpark DataFrame from Pandas
sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
sparkDF.printSchema()

print("Following is the given twitter chatgpt files")
sparkDF.show(n=10, truncate=True)
```

Output is as follows :

```
Given pandas dataframe name
                        Datetime             Tweet Id                                               Text         Username                                          Permalink                                 User                                           Outlinks                                         CountLinks  ReplyCount  RetweetCount  LikeCount  QuoteCount       ConversationId Language                                             Source                                              Media                                        QuotedTweet                                     MentionedUsers                                            hashtag  hastag_counts
0      2023-01-22 13:44:34+00:00  1617156270871699456  ChatGPTで遊ぶの忘れてた！！\n書類作るコード書いてみてほしいのと、\nどこまで思考整...      mochico0123  https://twitter.com/mochico0123/status/1617156...      https://twitter.com/mochico0123                                                NaN                                                NaN           1             0          5           0  1617156270871699456       ja  <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                 []              0
1      2023-01-22 13:44:39+00:00  1617156291046133761  @AlexandrovnaIng Prohibition of ChatGPT has be...  Caput_LupinumSG  https://twitter.com/Caput_LupinumSG/status/161...  https://twitter.com/Caput_LupinumSG                                                NaN                                                NaN           1             0          5           0  1617148639993806848       en  <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...                                                NaN                                                NaN  [User(username='AlexandrovnaIng', id=282705900...                                                 []              0
2      2023-01-22 13:44:44+00:00  1617156308926349312  Schaut Euch an, was @fobizz @DianaKnodel alles...            ciffi  https://twitter.com/ciffi/status/1617156308926...            https://twitter.com/ciffi  ['https://us02web.zoom.us/webinar/register/801...  ['https://twitter.com/DsoeVJrPBp', 'https://twitter.com/HflT...           0             0          4           0  1617156308926349312       de  <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/download/ipad" ...  [Photo(previewUrl='https://pbs.twimg.com/media...  https://twitter.com/DianaKnodel/status/1617153...  [User(username='fobizz', id=884708145792253952...                                       ['#ChatGPT']              1
3      2023-01-22 13:44:49+00:00  1617156332297256961  Bow down to chatGPT ..... https://twitter.com/ENTSzi...    Vishwasrisiri  https://twitter.com/Vishwasrisiri/status/16171...    https://twitter.com/Vishwasrisiri  ['https://twitter.com/agadmator/status/1617155...                        ['https://twitter.com/ENTSzi2AQ9']           0             0          2           0  1617156332297256961       en  <a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" ...                                                NaN  https://twitter.com/agadmator/status/161715501...                                                NaN                                                 []              0
4      2023-01-22 13:44:52+00:00  1617156345064570880  Profilinde vatan, Türkiye falan yazan bireyler...   0xGenetikciniz  https://twitter.com/0xGenetikciniz/status/1617...   https://twitter.com/0xGenetikciniz                                                NaN                                                NaN           0             0          4           0  1617156345064570880       tr  <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                 []              0
...                          ...                  ...                                                ...              ...                                                ...                                  ...                                                ...                                                ...         ...           ...        ...         ...                  ...      ...                                                ...                                                ...                                                ...                                                ...                                                ...            ...
49996  2023-01-24 06:57:56+00:00  1617778712082096128  #ChatGPT ist ein #Chatbot, der durch künstlich...     HorstKrieger  https://twitter.com/HorstKrieger/status/161777...     https://twitter.com/HorstKrieger  ['https://linked.in/dzHbz5-z', 'https://linked.in/...  ['https://twitter.com/qxUJZinuNO', 'https://twitter.com/lFZD...           0             0          0           0  1617778712082096128       de  <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" rel="nofoll...                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN  ['#ChatGPT', '#Chatbot,', '#KI', '#AI', '#Dial...              6
49997  2023-01-24 06:57:59+00:00  1617778726393249792  @r8r Ich hab mal die AI dazu befragt (ChatGPT)...            werpu  https://twitter.com/werpu/status/1617778726393...            https://twitter.com/werpu                                                NaN                                                NaN           0             0          0           0  1617774521586708480       de  <a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofo...  [Photo(previewUrl='https://pbs.twimg.com/media...                                                NaN  [User(username='r8r', id=15451529, displayname...                                                 []              0
49998  2023-01-24 06:58:00+00:00  1617778728481992705  5 minuti di #chatGPT e ho capito che apprende ...   marcopiccinini  https://twitter.com/marcopiccinini/status/1617...   https://twitter.com/marcopiccinini                                                NaN                                                NaN           0             0          0           0  1617778728481992705       it  <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...  [Photo(previewUrl='https://pbs.twimg.com/media...                                                NaN                                                NaN                                       ['#chatGPT']              1
49999  2023-01-24 06:58:01+00:00  1617778731678044162  Portland Shop Uses ChatGPT To Tell Family Stor...    EuniceNyandat  https://twitter.com/EuniceNyandat/status/16177...    https://twitter.com/EuniceNyandat                     ['https://drumup.io/s/DkswB6']                        ['https://twitter.com/rzGvr6yTOc']           0             0          0           0  1617778731678044162       en  <a href="https://drumup.io" rel="nofollow">dru...                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                 []              0
50000  2023-01-24 06:58:01+00:00  1617778733355790342  Ahora sueño con el día en que Amazon integre u...     AmericoSD_69  https://twitter.com/AmericoSD_69/status/161777...     https://twitter.com/AmericoSD_69                                                NaN                                                NaN           0             0          0           0  1617778733355790342       es  <a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" ...                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                 []              0

[50001 rows x 20 columns]
23/11/28 13:54:39 WARN SparkSession: Using an existing Spark session; only runtime SQL configurations will take effect.
root
 |-- Datetime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Tweet Id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Username: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Permalink: string (nullable = true)
 |-- User: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Outlinks: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CountLinks: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ReplyCount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- RetweetCount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- LikeCount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- QuoteCount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ConversationId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Language: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Media: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QuotedTweet: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MentionedUsers: string (nullable = true)
 |-- hashtag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- hastag_counts: long (nullable = true)

Following is the given twitter chatgpt files
23/11/28 13:54:43 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (31565 KiB). The maximum recommended task size is 1000 KiB.
23/11/28 13:54:48 WARN PythonRunner: Detected deadlock while completing task 0.0 in stage 0 (TID 0): Attempting to kill Python Worker
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+-------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|            Datetime|           Tweet Id|                          Text|       Username|           Permalink|                User|            Outlinks|          CountLinks|ReplyCount|RetweetCount|LikeCount|QuoteCount|     ConversationId|Language|              Source|               Media|         QuotedTweet|      MentionedUsers|             hashtag|hastag_counts|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+-------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|2023-01-22 13:44:...|1617156270871699456|ChatGPTで遊ぶの忘れてた！！...|    mochico0123|https://twitter.c...|https://twitter.c...|                 NaN|                 NaN|         1|           0|        5|         0|1617156270871699456|      ja|<a href="http://t...|                 NaN|                 NaN|                 NaN|                  []|            0|
|2023-01-22 13:44:...|1617156291046133761|          @AlexandrovnaIng ...|Caput_LupinumSG|https://twitter.c...|https://twitter.c...|                 NaN|                 NaN|         1|           0|        5|         0|1617148639993806848|      en|<a href="http://t...|                 NaN|                 NaN|[User(username='A...|                  []|            0|
|2023-01-22 13:44:...|1617156308926349312|          Schaut Euch an, w...|          ciffi|https://twitter.c...|https://twitter.c...|['https://us02web...|['https://twitter.com/Ds...|         0|           0|        4|         0|1617156308926349312|      de|<a href="http://t...|[Photo(previewUrl...|https://twitter.c...|[User(username='f...|        ['#ChatGPT']|            1|
|2023-01-22 13:44:...|1617156332297256961|          Bow down to chatG...|  Vishwasrisiri|https://twitter.c...|https://twitter.c...|['https://twitter...|['https://twitter.com/EN...|         0|           0|        2|         0|1617156332297256961|      en|<a href="http://t...|                 NaN|https://twitter.c...|                 NaN|                  []|            0|
|2023-01-22 13:44:...|1617156345064570880|          Profilinde vatan,...| 0xGenetikciniz|https://twitter.c...|https://twitter.c...|                 NaN|                 NaN|         0|           0|        4|         0|1617156345064570880|      tr|<a href="http://t...|                 NaN|                 NaN|                 NaN|                  []|            0|
|2023-01-22 13:45:...|1617156376983207937|          ChatGPT’nin bilin...|  GazeteKarinca|https://twitter.c...|https://twitter.c...|['https://gazetek...|['https://twitter.com/da...|         0|           0|        1|         0|1617156376983207937|      tr|<a href="https://...|                 NaN|                 NaN|                 NaN|                  []|            0|
|2023-01-22 13:45:...|1617156389217894400|          ChatGPT runs 10K ...| FierceElectron|https://twitter.c...|https://twitter.c...|['https://www.fie...|['https://twitter.com/Uh...|         0|           0|        0|         0|1617156389217894400|      en|<a href="https://...|                 NaN|                 NaN|                 NaN|                  []|            0|
|2023-01-22 13:45:...|1617156393898745858|          @SWENGDAD There i...|     xlr8harder|https://twitter.c...|https://twitter.c...|                 NaN|                 NaN|         1|           0|        3|         0|1617149595901104130|      en|<a href="https://...|                 NaN|                 NaN|[User(username='S...|                  []|            0|
|2023-01-22 13:45:...|1617156404137295878|          I created a ficti...|    Kosuke_dazo|https://twitter.c...|https://twitter.c...|['https://oriori....|['https://twitter.com/gt...|         0|           1|        2|         1|1617156404137295878|      en|<a href="http://t...|[Photo(previewUrl...|                 NaN|                 NaN|['#ChatGPT', '#mi...|            2|
|2023-01-22 13:45:...|1617156405869379585|          It will look simi...|    EricRIngram|https://twitter.c...|https://twitter.c...|                 NaN|                 NaN|         0|           0|        0|         0|1617156405869379585|      en|<a href="http://t...|[Photo(previewUrl...|                 NaN|                 NaN|        ['#ChatGPT']|            1|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+-------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```